# How to disable a design:attribute so that user can only read the default value

Tags: lightning-experience, app-builder, design-attributes

This may take away purpose of designer attributes, but still I want to ask , How can a design:attribute be disabled so that user can only read the default value. This is to make user aware that this is the default value and can not be changed.

Is this supported at all by salesforce?

Comment: Why not just make an aura attribute and set a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs:

> Use a design resource to control which attributes are exposed to
>   builder tools like the Lightning App Builder, Community Builder, or
>   Cloud Flow Designer.

So this the main purpose of tool to allow basic customization from end user perspective.

So you can either use `aura:attribute` but you can't make `design:attribute` readonly for them.

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with Tushar's answer, there is one simple way this can be done. Make a designer attribute of type picklist and keep a single value in it, not even a blank value.